# Problem with Hyper-V guest services install on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hyper-v

We are trying to setup Windows 7 clients under Hyper-V for testing; however, guest services are not installing.  Are there new guest services available, or is there a way to force the install on Windows 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you running one of the supported hosts? "The guest operating systems are supported for Hyper-V in Windows Server 2008 R2, Hyper-V in Windows Server 2008 with Service Pack 2, and Hyper-V version 1 (KB950050, “Hyper-V Update for Windows Server 2008 x64 Edition”)."

See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc794868(WS.10).aspx

Various Pages state that the integration components are already installed in Windows 7.

e.g.: http://blogs.msdn.com/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2009/01/12/windows-7-on-hyper-v.aspx

Comment: I'll vote for "already installed" - my Win7 virtual shows up in SCVMM as VM Additions Detected, though there's nothing to remove.

Comment: Yes, I believe Windows 7 already has the integration components installed.

Comment: Wow, that was a brain dead moment.  You are correct. :)